# Use custom directory for apt-get?

Tags: apt

When we run `apt-get update` ubuntu read URLS from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and package information save in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

Can i customize this directories? Without harm `/var/apt/lists` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`. When I want to install a package using apt-get it will read package information from a specific directory (`/custom/apt/lists`) instead of `/var/lib/apt/lists` and update from `/custom/apt/sources.list` instead of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, the two things you are looking for are:

- The equivalent to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` is `Dir::Etc::SourceParts`.
- The `/etc/apt/sources.list` equivalent is `Dir::Etc::SourceList`
- The `/var/lib/apt/lists/` equivalent is `Dir::State::Lists`

There are a bunch of them in the `apt-get` man page. An example using all of them:

```
apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::SourceParts "/some/path/with/lists/" -o Dir::Etc::SourceList "some.list" -o Dir::State::Lists "/custom/apt/lists"
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add a file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with just the path to the folder where the deb files are (but this folder has to contain a file called `Packages` generated by `dpkg-scanpackages`), then `apt update`, then install whatever packages I need from that folder, and then remove the file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` again, and call `apt update` again.

This is an example of the file that can get copied to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
deb file:///path/to/where/your/deb/files/are/ ./
```

Problem about this approach is that you have to call `apt update` with the flags `--allow-insecure-repositories --allow-unauthenticated` and call `apt install` with the flag `--allow-unauthenticated`.

I've had to do this to create a script that downloads .deb files of apt packages (and their dependencies) recursively. If you want to take a look, this is the relevant commit that implements the above: https://github.com/nblockchain/geewallet/commit/dea77d07c40dd63a82094c65635fdd73c7bfbcc4